# How to not have cuts in model when moving rig

Tags: rigging, objects

When I try move and/or rotate the rig for the model, some weird cuts appear in the object like this. Is it possible to not have any and avoid this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Most likely you have disconnected/duplicated vertices in the mesh. Use "merge by distance".

Comment: @no-can-do umm, how can i do this? Sorry, I'm kind of new to blender and its functions. Thanks

Comment: To "merge by distance" you can find it here https://i.gyazo.com/76eaa3a2413254dab51a4bb00c0a1ef9.png or use the search function (default F3 or space) and typing in "merge by distance"